# How do I get the http headers from a mediawiki extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki

**Problem**

I would like to examine the http headers from within a media wiki extension. Specifically if one of the headers exists, I will take an action.

**Background**

I am a newbie to php and mediawiki. I am working on my second extension in mediawiki. I want to take a specific action if a particular http header is part of the page request. I am now confident that the hook is being called at the correct time, but unfortunately I cannot seem to get hold of the http headers.

```
$extensionObject = new MyExtension;
$wgHooks['ArticlePageDataBefore'][] = array($extensionObject, 'onArticlePageDataBefore');

class MyExtension{
    public function onArticlePageDataBefore( &$article, &$fields ) {
        $headers =mygetallheaders();
        ...do something with the headers
        return true;
    }
    public function mygetallheaders()   {
        ...this is the function I am trying to write
        return $headers;
    }
```

**Software stack**

- MediaWiki: 1.20.2
- PHP: 5.3.3 (apache2handler)
- MySQL: 5.1.61

**Tried so far.**

The following two methods both return an empty array

- apache_request_headers
- getallheaders

The $_SERVER variable is empty

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

```
public function onArticlePageDataBefore( &$article, &$fields ) {
    global $wgRequest;
    if ( $wgRequest->getHeader( 'My-Cool-Header' ) == 42 {
            PROFIT!
    }
    return true;
}
```